# Ruby on rails : Display a pdf file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am uploading PDF files using paperclip, how do I display them after?

This is the error I get:
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/public/uploads/6/test.pdf"):

I mean ok I know it's a routing error but do I have to define a route for every file? it doesn't make sense to me

Comment: you do not have to define a route to it, just link to it properly just like you would an image, when you upload it where does it go?  Are you developing locally right now or on a hosted site somewhere?

Comment: I'm still testing locally, I defined the default url on a folder called uploads so basically for a file with id = 1 it goes to /public/uploads/6/test.pdf

Comment: OMG I have been always including /public ..  thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to define a route to it, just link to it properly just like you would an image

Your url linking to the asset is incorrect.  Remove the `/pulbic` so it looks like below.

```
'/uploads/6/test.pdf'
```